# Memory Leak when making a data-aware version of a custom component in Delphi

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-11-alexandria

I have coded a data-aware version of a custom component, following this tutorial:
https://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+17+Writing+Database+Components/Writing+Field-Oriented+Data-Aware+Controls/

It works fine, but I get a memory leak every time that I close manually the dataset linked to the component (if I leave the dataset to be automatically closed when releasing the form, then no memory leak is triggered).

The parent TkpEntityEdit is a panel with two TcxTextEdit (one to edit/search a key and the second to visualize its description), and the KeyChange(NewKey: variant); method overriden here is triggered every time the user sets a new key. But I don't think there is any problem in that parent component, it looks like that I'm missing to clear something when FDatalink.OnDataChange notifies me that the dataset has been closed.

```
unit DBEntityEdit;

interface

uses EntityEdit, 
     System.Classes, System.SysUtils, Data.DB, VCL.DBCtrls;

type
  TKpDBEntityEdit = class(TKpEntityEdit)
  private
    FDataLink: TFieldDataLink;
    function GetDataField: string;
    procedure SetDataField(Value: string);
    function GetDataSource: TDataSource;
    procedure SetDataSource(Value: TDataSource);
    procedure CheckActive;
  protected
    procedure KeyChange(NewKey: variant); override;
    procedure DataChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure UpdateData(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ActiveChange(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create (AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property DataField: string read GetDataField write SetDataField;
    property DataSource: TDataSource read GetDataSource write SetDataSource;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  {$IFDEF WIN32}
  RegisterComponents('My Components', [TKpDBEntityEdit]);
  {$ENDIF}
end;

constructor TKpDBEntityEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create (AOwner);
  FDataLink := TFieldDataLink.Create;
  FDataLink.Control := Self;
  FDataLink.OnDataChange := DataChange;
  FDataLink.OnUpdateData:= UpdateData;
  FDataLink.OnActiveChange := ActiveChange;
  FEditKey.Properties.ReadOnly := True;
end;

destructor TKpDBEntityEdit.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FDataLink);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TKpDBEntityEdit.ActiveChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckActive;
end;

procedure TKpDBEntityEdit.KeyChange(NewKey: variant);
var EventDataChange: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  EventDataChange := FDatalink.OnDataChange;
  FDatalink.OnDataChange := nil;
  FDatalink.Edit;
  FDatalink.OnDataChange := EventDataChange;

  UpdateData(Self);
end;

procedure TKpDBEntityEdit.CheckActive;
var Active: boolean;
begin
  Active := FDataLink.Active and Assigned(FDataLink.Field);

  FEditKey.Properties.ReadOnly := (not Active) or FDataLink.Field.ReadOnly;
end;

procedure TKpDBEntityEdit.DataChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FDatalink.Field)  then
    Self.Key := FDatalink.Field.Value;
end;

procedure TKpDBEntityEdit.UpdateData(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDataLink.Field.Value := Self.Key;
end;

function TKpDBEntityEdit.GetDataField: string;
begin
  Result := FDataLink.FieldName;
end;

procedure TKpDBEntityEdit.SetDataField(Value: string);
begin
  FDataLink.FieldName := Value;
  CheckActive;
end;

function TKpDBEntityEdit.GetDataSource: TDataSource;
begin
  Result := FDataLink.DataSource;
end;

procedure TKpDBEntityEdit.SetDataSource(Value: TDataSource);
begin
  FDataLink.DataSource := Value;
  CheckActive;
end;

end.
```

This is the memory leak warning.

[image]

What did I miss ?. Thank you.

Comment: Try one of the  [memory profilers for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76541156/1480104) to get call stacks of the leaks.